# Generating an acronim with a category that is made on the NSString class and printing out the initial letters as capital letters

Tags: objective-c

So how could we solve this exercise? I thougth about something like this:
- User is asked to enter a string
- The entered string is checked how many words does it have
-If the string consists of 1 word the first letter of this word is extracted, (like with an objectat) capitalized and printed out.

This may seem a bit strange from some of you but i try to figure it out the steps of resolving exercises simce i am still atbthe beginning of learning.

Answer (score 0):

Very error prone solution:

```
NSString *name = @"Peter justus Falk";
NSArray *names = [name componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *acronym = @"";

for (NSString *name in names) {
    acronym = [acronym stringByAppendingString:[name substringToIndex:1].capitalizedString];
}

NSLog(acronym);
```

-> `PJF`